# Is there any pre build nvidia - cpu miner for Centos

Tags: linux, compile

I need a pre-build CENTOS 7 monero miner.  I have been looking for the answer of this quesition for a while, I have found the similar questions as well. However, the answers are old (around 2016) and those miners does not run properly on my CentOS 7. I have a normal (non-root) in a CENTOS 7 server. However, I cannot run sudo on it. Therefore, I need a prebuild CENTOS 7 monero miner. 
However, I also came up with this idea to compile a miner on my personal CENTOS7 system and run the built one on the server? Since I am not too much familiar with linux programming, can anybody answer my question?

Comment: What miner do you prefer? xmrig, amr-stak - just name it.

Comment: it is not critical to me...each miner which works under the aforementioned situation

Comment: If you don't have root access on the server, sounds sketchy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See xmrig (on Github). After last update have static build. Download Centos 7 to you VM machine and build xmrig in machine. And after building just copy file to remote Centos server.
In xmrig issues have pre-build miner (from some user) but this is old version.

Comment: Thank you, so you mean I can build that last version [gpu and CPU ones] on my local machine / VM then I only need to use the executable file stand alone on the server? No need any other libraries, right?

Comment: @Berliner, yes.